# I want to degrade the serverless version from 2.41.2 to 2.35.0

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-offline

By mistake I had installed the higher version of serverless on my pc. Now I want to degrade my serverless framework version from `v2.41.2` to `v2.35.0` due to some project requirements.

What I had tried to do:

I uninstalled the current serverless framework with `npm uninstall -g serverless`.

Then ran this command `npm install -g serverless@2.35.0`

But when I ran this command `serverless --version` it is still showing the version 2.41.2 on my pc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to being installed globally via NPM, `serverless` can also be a project dependency. If you're working in a node project, ensure that `serverless` isn't listed in the `package.json` file or in the `package-lock.json` file.

If so, run `npm uninstall serverless` and then `npm install -d serverless@2.35.0`, to install the framework in the project at the correct version.

Comment: I had currently installed it globally, if I add it as a dev dependency in my project it would work fine?

Comment: Yes, it'll install the package locally and resolve it from `node_modules` in the project before looking at global node modules.

Comment: what does -d means in the npm install command?

Comment: It instructs npm to install the specified package as a development dependency, one not needed for the application in production (like a test suite, or in this case, serverless framework).